# Images not uploading in phone gap mobile app

Tags: android, html, css, image, phonegap-build

I am build phone gap web app. I have to upload images from client side using multipart/form-data and backend in nodejs.
This code works well for some mobile phones,but not working for some mobiles especially Samsung Tab 4, HUAWEI.(  when open in these devices, on click nothing happens, even same code works well in other devices)

```
<form id = "uploadForm" enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post">
         <!--- <img src="../Images/gallery_image.PNG" width="68px" height="auto" id="image_1"/> -->
         <div id="image_1" style="    position: relative;
    width: 68px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url(../Images/gallery_image.PNG);
    display: block;
    left: 9%;
    bottom: 2px;
    background-size: cover;">
          <input type="file" id="imgInp"  name="userPhoto" size="60" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg" style="    width: 60px;
    height: 67px;    opacity: 0;"/><br />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Gallery" name="submit" id="submit_gallery" class="myButton_00" style="right: 9%;position: relative;top:5px;">

          </form>
```